# Highlighting newest post until a certain date

Tags: php

I'm trying to use DateTime to determine how long a newly posted comic should stay highlighted for. So, my goal is to have the latest comic "highlighted" for 2 days, then go back to regular (gray, like the rest).

**Note**: this is a question I've asked before. I'm restating it because the previous question was becoming quite confusing for people. So I reworked the code, simplified my question, and am re-asking.

[image]

**My logic:**

```
Loop through all comics {
   if comic date >= current date, display that comic with highlight CSS tag, 

   else display it with normal CSS tag.
}
```

**My code:** I'm wondering why this isn't working... it's not even displaying the latest comic (whose date > current_date).

```
        $desc = (isset($_GET['description']) ? ($_GET['description']) : null);  


    $row = $catResult->fetch_assoc();

    $current_date = new DateTime;
    echo "Current Date: " . $current_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    //$comic_date->modify('3 day');

    //DISPLAY IMAGES TO CORRECT PAGE FROM DATABASE  

            echo '<ul>';
        $imageCounter = 0;
        while (($imageCounter < $imagesPerPage) && ($row = $catResult->fetch_assoc())) {

            $comic_date = new DateTime($row['date']);

            $class = ($comic_date >= $current_date) ? 'newcomics' : 'comics';   
                echo '<li>';                
                    echo        '<span class="' . $class . '"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site='.$site. '&id=' . $row['id'] .'" title="' . $row['description'] . '" alt="' . $row['title'] . '">
                                <img src="./scripts/thumber.php?img=.' . $thumbpath.$row['thumb'] . '&mw=220&mh=220"/></a> 
                                <br /><br /> ' . $row['description'] . $row['date'] . '</span>';                                
                    $imageCounter++;
                echo '</li>';


            }   
        echo '</ul>';
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ternary conditional is set up so that is the condition is true, you only output `<span class="newcomics">` and nothing else (not the anchor tag etc.).

I'd recommend doing it like this to make it more readable:

```
$class = ($row['date'] >= $current_date) ? 'newcomic' : 'comic'

echo '<span class="' . $class . '"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site='.$site. '&id=' . $row['id'] .'" title="' . $row['description'] . '" alt="' . $row['title'] . '"><img src="./scripts/thumber.php?img=.' . $thumbpath.$row['thumb'] . '&mw=220&mh=220"/></a> <br /><br /> ' . $row['description'] . $row['date'] . '</span>';
```

Comment: Are you still having trouble? If so, can you also show us the generated HTML (right click -> view source)

Comment: Seems to be solved... but it was only solved when I put '$comic_date = new DateTime($row['date']);' in the while loop, and compared using DateTime... Im wondering why I couldnt have just compared against $row['date']?  As in:  $class = ($row['date'] >= $current_date) ? 'newcomics' : 'comics';.... Why does it have to be a new DateTime when they both echo out to be the same format?

Comment: any idea? Is it because DateTime is an object, and $row['date'] is a string, so you can't compare them directly?

Comment: you can convert $row['date'] to a Date object too. if it's a unix timestamp, do `date('format', $row['date'])`. If it's a string, use `strtotime()`.